# Using multiple interface inheritance to shape Req Res Asp .Net Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, multiple-inheritance

I am building a WebApi in asp .Net Core have three interfaces like these:

```
public interface IBook
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Author { get; set; }
    long Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IBookReq
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Author { get; set; }
}

public interface IBookRes
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    long Id { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is to implement Book as:

```
public class Book : IBook, IBookReq, IBookRes
{
    //Not Implemented 
}
```

So I can have different representations of Book instances in different part of my WebApi project, and I am not sure how to cast Book to specific interface.

Comment: You don't need to cast it at all.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Nitpick: This isn't inheritance, it's implementing interfaces. You can only inherit from a class.

Comment: I am basically trying to avoid Dtos and ObjectMapping. Let's say Book is returned from data access layer and I only want to have specific properties of Book in my controller response or only bind to specific properties in the request.

Comment: Interfaces aren't going to help you here then. Instead you need concrete classes and map between them. You can use a library like AutoMapper to simplify this.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of Mapping? The more I think about it Book, BookReq and BookRes have different subset of properties of the same object (Book)

Comment: Whatever you do will still need some sort of mapping. Even if you pass around your `Book` as one of the interfaces, it's still a `Book` with all the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a BookViewModel or DTO to use as your wire format. It’s not a good idea to expose your domain/data model via your API as you seem to already know. As comments have suggested, you can use a tool like Automapper to make it easy to go between wire format classes and data/domain classes.